# Sloved - Building a websocket server over Cloudflare

Tags: websocket, cloudflare

Recently I'm building a web server on port 80(SSL over Cloudflare), and I have another websocket server on port 81, the website worked fine but it's always failed when it connect to websocket server.

By the way, if I directly input the ip address it's working.

Example:
ws://domain.com:81 -> Failed

wss://domain.com:81 -> Failed

ws://ipaddress:81 -> Successfully

Any idea would be very appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloudflare, expose ip on other ports purposely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65631707/cloudflare-expose-ip-on-other-ports-purposely)

Comment: No, but I appreciate the time you took to help me :)

Comment: It does sound a _lot_ like you're trying to expose port 81, which is a port other than 80 or 443. That answer explains why that won't work.

Comment: I get it, I thought I can build up a web server and websocket server over CloudFlare at the same time, thank you!